# AngularJS binding to date inputs

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope binding to a HTML5 date input. The scope binds fine when I select a date using the calendar pop-out, or when I manually type in a date. But the binding is gone whenever I change the month using the arrow keys. How do I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/hientc/5zzwL30z/1/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <input type="date" ng-model="date" />
        {{ date }}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.date = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
});
```

Since a lot of people are confused, here's a image showing the steps. 
[image]

Comment: in Chrome and Firefox its working, which browser you are trying

Comment: do you mean when you clear out the date and start using the arrow key? If so i think it waits for the entire date to get filled and then it binds with the view.

Comment: GeekOnGadgets: no, the problem occurs when I try to change the month using the arrow buttons.

TheSharpieOneSame: same results with Angular 1.3.0.

Comment: For me, this code works fine on Chrome. The only problem I see is when I change the date from: 10/31/2014 - the default date to: 09/31/2014 -> but this in normal because it is not a valid date.

Comment: I will suggest not to rely on Chrome date picker since it will be not cross browser use some alternate option, its seems like a bug

Comment: your solution, only works on Chrome. I tested on IE and Firefox. These arrows does not appear. I would suggest to use some-other approach for date picker.